# Minimal to effort to have a JS beautifier on vim

Tags: vimrc, filetype-javascript

My research hints that there is no way to have a JS file properly formatted without going through installations.

I wonder whether there is a minimal effort way of doing it in vim.
What are your opinions on that one? What do you recommend? Can't this be achieved by an appropriate configuration of a `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 8):

I recommend filtering your buffer/file through a node module called [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) (also available as a python module):

```
:%!js-beautify -f -        " whole buffer
:'<,'>!js-beautify -f -    " selected lines
```

Here is the custom command I have in `after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`:

```
command! -buffer -range=% Format let b:winview = winsaveview() |
    \ execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "!js-beautify -f - -j -t -s " . &shiftwidth |
    \ call winrestview(b:winview)
```

That command works on the whole buffer by default or on any range, while keeping the cursor position and, *more or less*, respecting indentation settings.

Read `$ js-beautify --help` for the available options.